# Intuition for Ellipsoid Semi-axis Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, ellipsoids

**Background:**
I am trying to develop an understanding of the equation for semi-axes of an ellipsoid.

Consider the general form of an ellipsoid with a center at $\vec{s}$:
$$
\left[
  \begin{matrix}
      x & y & z & 1\\
  \end{matrix}
\right]
\mathbf E
\left[
  \begin{matrix}
      x\\
      y\\
      z\\
      1\\
  \end{matrix}
\right]
=
0
$$

$$
Where\
\mathbf E =  
\begin{pmatrix}
    a & h & g & p\\
    h & b & f & q\\
    g & f & c & r\\
    p & q & r & d
  \end{pmatrix}
=
\left[
  \begin{array}{c|c}
    \mathbf M_{3x3} & \vec{\mathbf n}\\
  \hline
    \vec{\mathbf n}^T & d\\
  \end{array}
\right]
$$

In the case of an axis aligned ellipsoid at the origin, the eigenvalues represent the squares of the reciprocals of the semi axes. However in the case that an ellipsoid is at some arbitrary rotation and location in space, the semi-axes can be determined like so:

$$
L_1 = \sqrt{\frac{\mathbf{\vec{n}}^T\mathbf{M}^{-1}\mathbf{\vec{n}} - d}{\lambda_1}} = \sqrt{\frac{\mathbf{\vec{s}}^T\mathbf{M}\mathbf{\vec{s}} - d}{\lambda_1}}
$$

$L_2$ and $L_3$ are the same except divided by their respective eigenvalues.

**My Question:**

What is the intuition behind the $(\mathbf{\vec{n}}^T\mathbf{M}^{-1}\mathbf{\vec{n}} - d)$ and $(\mathbf{\vec{s}}^T\mathbf{M}\mathbf{\vec{s}} - d)$ terms arise from? These terms are identical, seem to come from nowhere, and I can't wrap my head around what they **mean**.

I would appreciate an explanation on where they come from.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Compare $x^TMx+2n\cdot x+d$ and $(x-s)^TM(x-s)$, and using $M=U\Lambda U^T$ where $U$ is orthogonal.

Comment: Ah yes! I have noticed how the $(x-s)$ term "changes" the $d$ value of the ellipsoid and that then must influence the semi-axis values, but I'm sorry to say I still can't see how to go from there to the $L_1, etc.$ equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the position vector of a point on the ellipsoid as ${r} = [x, y, z]^T$

Then the equation of the ellipsoid is:

$ r^T M r + 2 r^T n + d = 0$

Define $s = -M^{-1} n$ , then the above quadratic equation becomes,

$ (r - s)^T M (r - s) - s^T M s + d = 0$

i.e.

$ (r - s)^T M (r - s) = s^T M s - d $

Dividing by the right side,

$ (r - s)^T G (r - s) = 1 $

where $G = \dfrac{1}{s^T M s - d} M$

The last equation is the standard equation of an ellipsoid with center at $s$.  The semi-axes lengths of this ellipsoid are the square root of the receiprocals of the eigenvalues of $G$.  The eigenvalues of $G$ are a scaled version of the eigenvalues of matrix $M$ by a factor of $\dfrac{1}{s^T M s - d }$, hence,

$ \lambda_{Gi} = \dfrac{\lambda_{Mi}}{s^T M s - d} $

And therefore the semi-axes lengths are

$ L_i = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_{Gi}}} = \sqrt{ \dfrac{s^T M s - d}{ \lambda_{Mi} }}$

Finally we note that $s^T M s - d = (-M^{-1} n)^T M (- M^{-1} n ) - d = n^T M^{-1} n - d$

Comment: I've been working on this problem this is a part of for a month, and in classic math fashion seeing it worked out makes it seem so simple. That very last step is super helpful, thanks. Could you expand on how you get $(r - s)^T M (r - s) - s^T M s + d = 0$? I'm afraid I don't fully follow this step.

Comment: This is completing the quadratic form, we are starting with $r^T M r + 2 r^T n$, define $s = - M^{-1} n$ then$ (r - s)^T M (r - s) = r^T M r - 2 r^T M s + s^T M s = r^T M r + 2 r^T n + s^T M s$.  Hence $r^T M r + 2 r^T n = (r - s)^T M (r - s) - s^T M s$

Comment: So it's almost like there's some term matching going on? Comparing the general ellipsoid equation with $d$ and $n$ to the $(r-s)^T M (r-s)$ form? Why isn't the required information "baked in" to the first equation?

Comment: The general equation you started with is an expansion of the standard equation in which the center is specified explicitly.  So what I have done is basically compact the general equation into the standard equation, i.e. going in a backward direction to expansion.

Comment: These are some great details, writing it out myself and doing the substitutions directly helped make things click. Thank you for your help. The purpose of this whole process is to get the $\vec{x}^T E \vec{x} = 0$ form into the $Quadric = 1$ form so we can extract the semi-axis lengths simply, correct? Or is there a more eloquent way of describing what this process _means_ in an intuitive/qualitative way?

Comment: Yes.  That's exactly what it is.  Glad that you found this exercise helpful.